# Selecting a single row for each distinct combination in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Please consider this table:

```
firstName |  lastName | hobby
-----------------------------
Mike      |  Stone    | music
Sarah     |  James    | cooking
Mike      |  Stone    | jogging
Greg      |  Jones    | reading
Sarah     |  James    | music
Mike      |  Stone    | painting
-----------------------------
```

How do I select a single hobby (doesn't matter which), for each distinct firstName, lastName combination? (In Oracle)

An example of the desired result is:

```
firstName |  lastName | hobby
-----------------------------
Mike      |  Stone    | music
Sarah     |  James    | cooking
Greg      |  Jones    | reading
-----------------------------
```

Thank you for any assistance..

Sam

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like

```
select firstname, lastname, max(hobby) as hobby
   from names
   group by firstname, lastname
```

You could use other functions for max to give you different answers, for example, min.